# How can I create a triple-slash app link (deep link) in a Slack message created via API?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create an Asana app link but it seems Slack doesn't like it.  When I create the link via API, it shows as plain text, not a URL:

> asanadesktop:///app/0/0/1204843941664408|A.0265

This URL *does* work if created through the desktop Slack app and not through the API. And the same code works if the prefix is `https://` *or* `asanadesktop://` (double-slash) instead of `asanadesktop:///`.  I'm guessing Slack may be confused by the triple slash; but that syntax is required by Asana to get the correct deep link.

The code to create the message text is really simple:

```
const messageText = `:robot_face: <${taskLink}|${options.newTaskId}>\`;
```

It seems this may just be an issue where the Slack API cannot recognize a URL with three slashes.  Any idea how I can get Slack to treat this as a URL?